# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException = 0

Tags: java, jtable

> Got DBTableHeaderFill Error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException = 0

and can't figure it out, why does it appears...

col is 11 because table has 12 headers, as we know the counting starts form 0

i know it  looks primitive, but i'm just debugging the problem ...
JOptionPane is for seeing what works what not, and i can't figure whats the problem whit arrays...

```
    Object rows[][] = new Object[row][col];
    Object columns [] = new Object[col];
    row = 1;
    col = 11;
    JTable table = new JTable(rows, columns);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    /*
     *  DataBase Headers
     */
    try{
        conn = DBConnection.DBConnector();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Statement");
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Query1");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query1 load");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rsmd);
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, columnCount);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test " + col);
        // The column count starts from 0
        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) {
            columns[i-1] = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "result: " + o);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Header" + columns[i-1]);
          // Writes headers
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DBTableHeaderFill Error: " + e);
    }
```

When i assign col and row values before arrays i get this errors:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   javax.swing.JTable$1.getColumnName(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.JTable.addColumn(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JTable.setModel(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.JTable.(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JTable.(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JTable.(Unknown Source)     at
>   Main.initialize(Main.java:199)    at Main.(Main.java:65)    at
>   Main$1.run(Main.java:34)  at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

So i found my problem...

```
JTable table = new JTable(rows, columns);
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

this needs to be at the end of the arrays....

Comment: avoid catch(Exception e)
it's not a good practice

Comment: The exception occurs because your array is empty.

Comment: i can't avoid it because whit DataBase work i need try{}catche(){}

Comment: @user3481055 Really? You can't catch any other type?

Comment: He means you should catch specific exceptions, not `Exception`.

Comment: yes, but avoid a so general exception ... and a block so big.

Comment: Maybe you should set `row` and `col` before you reference them.

Comment: @ Hot Licks of course it's going be empty, i'm trying to fill the array

Comment: @Hot Licks     well when i do it it crashes, so... i'm in a dead end..

Comment: Note that your `for` loop, as written, will loop one less time than `columnCount`.

Comment: @Hot Licks     O, thanks, forgot about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are initialising your row/col values after using them to create the arrays:

```
Object rows[][] = new Object[row][col];
Object columns [] = new Object[col];
row = 1;
col = 11;
```

This should probably be:

```
row = 1;
col = 11;
Object rows[][] = new Object[row][col];
Object columns [] = new Object[col];
```

And col should be the exact number of columns your table has, otherwise you are creating an array that's only 11 elements long, instead of 12.

Comment: i know, but when i assign the int values before the arrays the whole thing just crashess

Comment: Then you should find out what causes these crashes. Creating an array with zero values will lead to an array with no elements, hence you can't even address array[0] as is your case.
`String[] strings = new String[0];
System.out.println(strings[0]);`
Leads to just the **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0** that you are experiencing

Comment: Thanks, some how forgot about that... got 2 projects going on... and the JTable elements by my look is one of the hardest...

Answer (score 0):

the variable col is set after:

```
Object columns [] = new Object[col];
```

What is the value of col, before this line?
If it is 0, then that would explain the error you are getting:

> Got DBTableHeaderFill Error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException = 0

Comment: it's 0 but when i assign it before, then the whole thing doesn't work...

Comment: You have to set it to 11, before using it in Object columns [] = new Object[col];